# linearly dependent linear tranformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be a vector space over $k$ of finite dimension $n$. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_p \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ with $p \leq n$ and assume that the $f_i$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (put it simply, there exists a basis of $E$, where the matrices representing the $f_i$ are all diagonal).

Assume that for all $x \in E$, the vectors $f_1(x), \ldots, f_p(x)$ are linearly dependent. Then the vectors $f_1, \ldots, f_p$ are linearly dependent in $\mathcal{L}(E)$.

I have a complicated proof of that, and I'd like to know if there is a simple argument proving this result. Furthermore, I feel like the diagonalizability assumption could be withdrawn and one could only assume that for any $i,j$ we have $f_i \circ f_j = f_j \circ f_i$, but I have no clue on how to prove that last assertion.

Comment: I don't have a reference on hand, but I'm pretty sure the $f_{i}$ will all pairwise commute if and only if they are simultaneously diagonalizable

Comment: @MorganRodgers : Of course, if you assume that all the $f_i$ pairwise commute and **are diagonalizable**, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable. In my second question, I withdraw the assumption that they are diagonalizable and only assume that they pairwise commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality $E=k^n$ and the $f_i$ are identified with diagonal matrices $D_i$ with $f_i\colon x\mapsto D_i x$. Now note that for $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and $\mathbf 1=(1,\dots,1)^t$ we have $D\mathbf 1 = (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)^t$.

So taking $x=\mathbf 1$ you get that the vectors $D_i\mathbf 1$, which consist of the diagonal entries of the $D_i$, are linearly dependent. Then of course the corresponding diagonal matrices satisfy the same linear relation.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that was so simple, I feel ashame I didn't find this neat argument.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample for the case when the matrices are not simultaneously diagonalisable:

$$f_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad f_2:=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $f_1,f_2$ are linearly independent, yet for any vector $x=(a,b)^t$, $$\tfrac{1}{a+b}f_1(x)+\tfrac{1}{a+2b}f_2(x)=0$$ (unless $a+b=0$ or $a+2b=0$; those cases correspond to eigenvectors of $f_1$, $f_2$ respectively, so $f_1(x)=0$ or $f_2(x)=0$, so $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$ are still dependent.)

---

Looking at the $2\times2$ case, commutativity of the matrices is not required for the property to hold; rather it is invertibility.

Suppose $f_1=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible and $f_2=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha a&\beta b\\\alpha c&\beta d\end{pmatrix}$ are as in the question. The second matrix must be of this form since $f_1(\mathbf{i})$, $f_2(\mathbf{i})$ are linearly dependent, and similarly $f_1(\mathbf{j})$, $f_2(\mathbf{j})$. Furthermore, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are in the same direction, hence if $x=(u,v)^t$, then $$\lambda\begin{pmatrix}au+bv\\cu+dv\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha au+\beta bv\\\alpha cu+\beta dv\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\therefore\ (au+bv)(\alpha cu+\beta dv)=(cu+dv)(\alpha au+\beta bv)$$ $$\therefore\ (\beta-\alpha)(ad-bc)uv=0$$ Hence $\alpha=\beta$, that is, $f_2=\alpha f_1$ as required.

Comment: Thanks, nice example! Though here $f_1$ and $f_2$ do not commute. I might be mistaken, but I have the feeling that the hypothesis $f_1$ and $f_2$ commutes is the key hypothesis (not the invertibility one).

Comment: @Libli When you analyse the $2\times2$ case, the determinant comes out as a factor. So two invertible $2\times2$ matrices have the required property without commuting.

Comment: that is very interesting. Could you ellaborate a bit on what you mean by "the determinant comes out as a factor"?

Comment: @Libli Added the requested part to the answer.

Comment: This is very interesting thanks. It seems your proof can be restated as follows. Let $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ ae linearly dependant for all $x \in E$. Since $f$ is invertible, one sees that $x$ and $f^{-1}(g(x))$ are linearly dependent for all $x \in E$. Then by Schur's lemma, $\mathrm{id}$ and $f^{-1} \circ g$ are linarly dependent in $\mathcal{L}(E)$, which proves that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent in $\mathcal{L}(E)$.

Comment: Nonetheless, I think the case of two endomorphisms is the tree that hides the forest. You are probably right that the invertibility of one of them will play an important role (as your example shows), but I am pretty sure that for 3 or more endomorphisms, pairwise commutativity will happen to be crucial.

Comment: @Libli You're probably right. The proof generalizes to any $n$ but I can't see how to extend it to three matrices.